# Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Emulator exited before boot en React Native when react-native run-android

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I am installing React Native according to this website https://medium.com/@leonardobrunolima/react-native-tips-setting-up-your-development-environment-for-windows-d326635604ea, it's very useful until I run the command `react-native run-android`, this is the error I receive:

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 864 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Emulator exited before boot..
> Task :app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
24 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 20 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.
> Could not read path 'C:\JesusApp\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\mergeJniLibs\debug\0\lib\x86_64'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.
> Could not read path 'C:\JesusApp\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\mergeJniLibs\debug\0\lib\x86_64'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (C:\JesusApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

My node version is 10, and I am working on Windows, please help, thank you.

Comment: Actually as per official site, install Node 14 or newer. Even I have the same, I used following commands to get v16. Remove the existing node first. Then try these.

1) curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
2) sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

It works well in ubuntu, please forgive if didn't work for other OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First start the android emulator on Android Studio, then execute the react-native run-android. If it doesn´t work go to android studio and do "Build -> Clean Project"

Comment: After this try to start AVD in Android Studio. 'Tools > AVD Manager' and them 'Launch AVD'

Answer (score 5):

I succeeded by doing the following steps:
Open android studio > AVD Manager > Actions (click the bottom icon) > Select Cool Boot Now.

Answer (score 4):

1. Check your config and environment setup with instructions [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup), be very careful with pathes set up. Check the $PATH from your IDE's terminal.
2. check in the AVD that a particular Android OS is selected and installed for a virtual device you use (in my case it was not, I had yellow warning exclaim sign in an "Actions" column in an AVD's devices list).
3. Have your Gradle updated to at least 6.6 in the

> android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

4. On Ubuntu after run I had to "push" switch-on button on the virtual device.

Finally, I got it up and running both on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Android 30.

Comment: And also, it's very strange that advices here below are downvoted. I tried purging data as it is adviced, but could not surely say, wether it lead to success or not. Cause I had to make some other experiments to succeed.

Answer (score 3):

This might be the insufficient space in your machine or AVD or the mismatch in the configurations.

So, do the following steps to resolve this issue.

- Verify that the environment variables are set for SDK path and adb.
- Clean the project by `Build -> Clean Project`
- Clean AVD by `Open android studio > AVD Manager > Actions (click the bottom icon) > Select Cool Boot Now`.

Answer (score 2):

For me running

```
adb kill-server
```

and

```
adb start-server
```

worked

I also runned `killall 9 node` before that but it was not enough. MacOS asks for saving last state before restart also Android emulator asks before quiting it. Maybe the problem happens because saving a bad state and trying to start from that bad state. Not sure but I suspect one of these.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've to wipe data on the virtual device.
Android Studio -> AVD -> Actions (↓) -> Wipe Data

Comment: I also do the same thing. But this is not a solution. Did you find a proper solution??

Comment: try deleting .gradle and build folder. and if it's not worked, try deleting the virtual device and create a new avd.

Comment: wiping data works for me. I want a time-saving solution. The solution you said will also work but it will waste my time.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem when executing my react-native code on **Android Physical device.** I am not sure if my solution will help.

We all know that ADB requires authorization from an Android device in order to communicate with it. It’s only by allowing the USB debugging and validating the computer’s RSA key fingerprint that we let the ADB daemon connect to our phone and control it. This is a security feature.

**My phone was connected with USB** and on changing USB Configuration on device, my phone gave me another prompt "Allow USB debugging?" [Image available for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk7SD.jpg). I got solution on **reallow** USB debugging

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, only check the developer options and enable the debug by usb, on the device

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem ended up being quite simple. Working in react-native, I was running the following command from the terminal 'npx react-native run-android' in VS CODE. Though the emulator would run fine when started from Android Studios, I received the above error when running from the terminal in VS Code.

Solution: Run VS Code as Administrator. (or your terminal in general)

Answer (score 0):

worked for me - there is not enough space on disk, Check that there is enough space on disk(where is the emulator was installed).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, cool boot and wipe data didn't work. I just uninstall the virtual device and reinstall it and then it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me - reload system or clean system/android cache ./android/avd

Answer (score -1):

Deleting the file `app\build\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json` worked for me.