# Failed to launch emulator on Android Studio

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, adb

I am currently building a react-native app and I get this error message everytime I run: **react-native run-android**

Error Message:

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1052 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Emulator exited before boot..
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_app
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at /Users/asakoulas/BODYBOX/Bodybox/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:firebase.bom using default value: 28.1.0
:react-native-firebase_app:play.play-services-auth using default value: 19.0.0
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at /Users/asakoulas/BODYBOX/Bodybox/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:version set from package.json: 12.1.0 (12,1,0 - 12001000)
:react-native-firebase_app:android.compileSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_app:android.targetSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_app:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:react-native-firebase_app:reactNativeAndroidDir /Users/myuser/appname/appname/node_modules/react-native/android
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 in /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 (revision: 30.0.2)".
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 (revision: 30.0.2)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 in /Users/asakoulas/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/30.0.2
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 (revision: 30.0.2)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 (revision: 30.0.2)" finished.
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
WARNING:: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (30.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 4.2.2.
Android SDK Build Tools 30.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
WARNING:: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (30.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 4.2.2.
Android SDK Build Tools 30.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Task :app:installDebug FAILED
Skipping device 'emulator-5554' (emulator-5554): Device is OFFLINE.
134 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 132 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No online devices found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No online devices found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s

    at makeError (/Users/username/Appname/app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/username/Appname/app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/username/Appname/app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/username/Appname/app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

The command (react-native run-android) was working perfecly until I tried to integrate Firebase and updated Android Studio.

I tried to do several things to fix this problem like reinstalling android studio or updating the sdk tools.

**When I run (react-native run-android), the JS server runs successfully and the android emulator opens but it doesn't download the app.**

And when I run: **adb devices** in my terminal I get:

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   offline
```

I already tried to delete, cold reboot, restart the emulator but it doesn't help and always shows **offline**.

I would really appreciate some help please.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I have also tried every suggestion I got related to this issue but none of them seems working and it drives me crazy sometimes. Please do share if some tricks have helped you, it would be an honor. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to manually open the simulator then run the command... if it doesn't work means its somewhere in your code... Or if its not in your code you can try to check one of these answers... [Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Emulator exited before boot en React Native when react-native run-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59495022/failed-to-launch-emulator-reason-emulator-exited-before-boot-en-react-native-w)

Sorry if i couldn't help...

Comment: I already tried everything and it didn't help unfortunately... It think the error is not with my code but related to adb or android studio. When I run "adb devices", I see the device but it is offline and I am not able to turn it back online. Thank you very much for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Please check below case's,

1. check wether you have installed emulator in the android studio.
   Android Studio > settings> System setting > Android SDK > select SDK tools Android Emulator
2. Check the compile SDK version in Build.Gradle in android. match the installed emulator version.